# Print filtered data from JSON in handlebars page

Tags: javascript, json

I have passed JSON from the server-side to the client-side. When I console, it shows correctly. I want to filter latest `rate` and `currency_id` for each `product_id`. I have mentioned it from an example below:

In the above JSON, If I consider `product_id` = `1` there are several records. But I want only the latest `rate` for each `currency_id`,

It means like below,

```
[
  {
      "currency_id": 1,
      "rate": 1.04
  },
  {
      "currency_id": 2,
      "rate": 1.05
  },
  {
      "currency_id": 3,
      "rate": 1.06
  }
]
```

I have used function for it,

```
COMNAME.prepEdit = function (id) {
    const cur = COMNAME.newCurrency.find((cur) => cur.product_id == id);
}
```

When I use the above function, I am getting only the first data in each product.

But I have no idea, how can I further implement this. I want your help to resolve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
COMNAME.prepEdit = function (product_id) {
    const currencyIds = [];
    const result = [];

    const sortData = COMNAME.newCurrency
        .filter((item) => item.product_id === product_id)
        .sort((item1, item2) => item1.id - item2.id);


    for (let i = sortData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const item = sortData[i];

        if(!currencyIds.includes(item.currency_id)) {
            currencyIds.push(item.currency_id)
            result.unshift(item);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: While code-only answers may solve the OP's problem, they aren't always useful to explain _why_ the solution works and how it helps solve the problem to the OP and future visitors. Including an explanation in your answer will improve it greatly.

Comment: @Sergey DanyleukoYour solution workes amazingly when for `"product_id": 1` but, `"product_id": 2` not works. it returns an empty array. But it also should return a valid array.

Comment: _it returns an empty array. But it also should return a valid array_ -> an empty array __is__ a valid array... do you mean it should return 2 items in the array (based on your sample input array)?

Comment: It works correctly for me when product_id = 2
please check again

Comment: I think you should add some comments to help the OP to understand his mistakes

Comment: @ Geoff James It should return only one. Because in `"product_id": 2` has only two records and both records are from the same `currency_id`. Then it should return only the latest data. it means it should return `"currency_id": 2, "rate": "1.07"`

Comment: Actually the problem is, In my system this workes correctly when 'product_id' has more than 3 records.

Answer (score 0):

for getting lasted rate for every product_id you should try:

```
latestRate=[]
newCurrency.forEach((currency)=>{
    if(!latestRate[currency.product_id]||latestRate[currency.product_id].rate<currency.rate)
        latestRate[currency.product_id]=currency
})
```

or for getting latest rate for currency and product:

```
prepEdit ={};
newCurrency.forEach((currency) => {
    if (!prepEdit[`${currency.product_id}-${currency.currency_id}`] || prepEdit[`${currency.product_id}-${currency.currency_id}`] < currency.rate)
        prepEdit[`${currency.product_id}-${currency.currency_id}`] = currency
})
prepEdit=Object.keys(prepEdit).map((obj)=>prepEdit[obj])
console.log(prepEdit)
```

Comment: there is a problem here. I want here, relevant to `product_id`. latest rates for each product. here there is a <a> for getting edit modal for each product.

Comment: When I try your new one I am getting `products:2453 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at Object.TYPEFI.prepEdit` error

Comment: are you using typescript?